# Netty DNS Answer Section not correctly decoded

Tags: java, dns, netty

I am working on a DNS-Client with netty.
To test it, I wrote a simple DNS-Server with netty, that returns DnsRecords which I am expecting.

Here is my client code:

```
final NioEventLoopGroup nioEventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
final EventLoop next = nioEventLoopGroup.next();
final DnsNameResolverBuilder dnsNameResolverBuilder = new 
DnsNameResolverBuilder(next).channelFactory(new ChannelFactory<DatagramChannel>() {
        @Override
        public DatagramChannel newChannel() {
            return new NioDatagramChannel();
        }
    }).queryTimeoutMillis(100000).nameServerAddresses(new 
        DnsServerAddresses() {
        @Override
        public DnsServerAddressStream stream() {
            return new DnsServerAddressStream() {
                @Override
                public InetSocketAddress next() {
                    return new InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 
                    TEST_DNS_SD_SERVER_PORT);
                }
            };
        }
    });
    final DnsNameResolver build = dnsNameResolverBuilder.build();
    final DefaultDnsQuestion defaultDnsQuestion = new 
    DefaultDnsQuestion(TEST_BASE_RECORD_NAME, DnsRecordType.PTR);
    build.query(defaultDnsQuestion).addListener(new GenericFutureListener<Future<? super AddressedEnvelope<DnsResponse, InetSocketAddress>>>() {
        @Override
        public void operationComplete(final Future<? super AddressedEnvelope<DnsResponse, InetSocketAddress>> future) throws Exception {
            final AddressedEnvelope<DnsResponse, InetSocketAddress> answer = (AddressedEnvelope<DnsResponse, InetSocketAddress>) future.get();
            final DnsResponse content = answer.content();
            final int count = content.count(DnsSection.ANSWER);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final DnsRecord recordAt = content.recordAt(DnsSection.ANSWER, i);
                System.out.println(recordAt);
            }
        }
    }).await();
    Thread.sleep(Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

`TEST_BASE_RECORD_NAME` is a record containing 3 DnsPtrRecords in the answer section.

Behind the `TEST_DNS_SD_SERVER_PORT` I am running a DNS-Server in a seperate thread, that handles requests in the following way:
(Part of LocalDNSSDHandler:)

```
public void channelRead(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx, final Object msg) { 
        final DatagramDnsQuery query = (DatagramDnsQuery) msg;
        DatagramDnsResponse defaultDnsResponse = null;
        try {
            final DnsRecord recordAt = query.recordAt(DnsSection.QUESTION);
            final Name name = Name.fromString(recordAt.name(), Name.root);
            final DnsEntryKey dnsEntryKey = 
            new DnsEntryKey(name, recordAt.type().intValue());
            final List<Record> list = 
            LocalTestServer.this.getDnsEntries().get(dnsEntryKey);
            defaultDnsResponse = 
            new DatagramDnsResponse(query.recipient(),
            query.sender(), query.id());
            defaultDnsResponse.addRecord(DnsSection.QUESTION, recordAt);
            for (final Record record : list) {
                final ByteBuf buffer = ctx.alloc().buffer();
                buffer.writeBytes(record.toWireCanonical());
                defaultDnsResponse.addRecord(DnsSection.ANSWER, new 
                DefaultDnsRawRecord(record.getName().toString(), 
                this.fromRecord(record), Long.MAX_VALUE, buffer));
            }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
        }
        ctx.writeAndFlush(defaultDnsResponse);
    }
```

The Server definies following `ChannelHandler`

```
public void initChannel(final DatagramChannel ch) throws Exception {
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new DatagramDnsResponseEncoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new DatagramDnsQueryDecoder());
                ch.pipeline().addLast(new LocalDNSSDHandler());
            }
```

What I am expecting in the client is to see 3 `System.out.println` for the 3 DnsPtrRecords I am expecting. But what I get is only 1.

When I debug it, I can see, that encoding/decoding on Server-side works fine.
But when the Client decodes the correspondending `ByteBuf` (which contains the Data I am expecting), it simply returns only 1 Record and skips the other 2 at this point in code:

(DatagramDnsResponseDecoder)

```
@Override
protected void decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, DatagramPacket packet, 
List<Object> out) throws Exception {
    final ByteBuf buf = packet.content();
    final DnsResponse response = newResponse(packet, buf);
    boolean success = false;
    try {
        final int questionCount = buf.readUnsignedShort();
        final int answerCount = buf.readUnsignedShort();
        final int authorityRecordCount = buf.readUnsignedShort();
        final int additionalRecordCount = buf.readUnsignedShort();
        decodeQuestions(response, buf, questionCount);
        decodeRecords(response, DnsSection.ANSWER, buf, answerCount);
        decodeRecords(response, DnsSection.AUTHORITY, buf,
        authorityRecordCount);
        decodeRecords(response, DnsSection.ADDITIONAL, buf, 
        additionalRecordCount);
        ...//source code of netty 4.1, trimmed
```

The `answerCount` is 3 as I am expecting. But when

`decodeRecords(response, DnsSection.ANSWER, buf, answerCount);`

is called, it will call

(DefaultDnsRecordDecoder)

```
protected DnsRecord decodeRecord(
        String name, DnsRecordType type, int dnsClass, long timeToLive,
        ByteBuf in, int offset, int length) throws Exception {
    if (type == DnsRecordType.PTR) {
        in.setIndex(offset, offset + length);
        return 
        new DefaultDnsPtrRecord(name, dnsClass, timeToLive, decodeName0(in));
    }
    return new DefaultDnsRawRecord(
            name, type, dnsClass, timeToLive, 
            in.retainedDuplicate().setIndex(offset, offset + length));
}
```

I don't understand the

`in.setIndex(offset, offset + length);`

since this sets the read AND write Index of the ByteBuf (in), and this will skip the other DnsRecords in the Answer section and makes it returing only one DnsRecord.

I am using Netty 4.1.4.Final

Comment: if you think there is a bug please open a bug-report in the netty issue trigger.

Comment: Issue added:
https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/5760

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Norman Maurer confirmed this as a Bug and fixed it in release:
4.1.6.Final

Thank you Norman!